# Google Geocoder API not working sometimes

Tags: android, google-geocoder

Hello Friends when i run google goecoder api in browser directlly
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=56.130366,-106.346771&sensor=true

and other link  like

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=canada&sensor=false

it gave me output like

```
{
 error_message: "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
 results: [ ],
 status: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Any idea why it is happen ?

Comment: You're not aware to their quota. 2,500 requests per 24 hour period

Comment: @Glenn--so googel can't handle request at a same time right ?

Answer (score 4):

There are Some Limitation for using free Google Map API. 
Geocode API has limit of 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.

You can see [DOC](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) for this API.

Hope it Helps!!